# Is it possible to access azure storage using wasb URI scheme in C#?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-data-lake, u-sql

Can we access Azure blob and Azure data lake store using wasb URI scheme in code behind file of U-SQL activity in C#. I have not observed any example/sample demonstrating this, and it is also not specified weather it is possible or not. If it is possible, please share some sample/example to use this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code-behind is just an easy way for you to create and use an assembly. So all the code in the code-behind has the same restrictions around accessing external resources as assembly code has.

So this means that you cannot access a blob or data lake file that way.

Instead, you should write your own custom extractor that processes the content of the file that is passed in using the EXTRACT statement. Some samples are provided on the GitHub site at https://github.com/MicrosoftBigData/usql/tree/master/Examples (see the dataformat example extractors for now, more examples for extractors are coming).

Comment: Thanks Michael for prompt answer.